# how to pass a parameter in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, dynamic, crystal-reports, command, report

I have a problem in Crystal reports 11. Because it has limitation to showing the information in dynamic reports and I have a huge list of customer, I want to write a query and ask the first letter of the customer name. If for example, it starts with A, just show the A customers.
this is my query:

```
select distinct bill_to_code
from TLORDER
where left(BILL_TO_CODE ,1 ) = ?
And CURRENT_STATUS <> 'CANCL' 
AND LEFT(BILL_NUMBER , 1 ) NOT IN ('M','U','T','K')
```

but when I copy this to crystal reports and create a parameter , I get an error

`Failed to retrieve data from the database`

I should mention that I have another sql query in this report .

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use Stored Procedure when trying to pass a parameter. [How to create SP](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/). Then used the SP for your report.